# Reading PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.0, itext, extract

This will be my first time reading a PDF.

I was searching around and found so options to do that with C# and choose to use iTextSharp.

So far I've done just the basic like reading the file and getting the content without issues.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(iPDF.Text);
for (int x = 2; x <= reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
{
    iResult.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.GetPageContent(x));
    break;
}
```

As you can see it is a very very basic code just to read the 2nd page of the PDF into a text file but, I've notice a lot of code into the text file and I am a bit lost on how to parse only the data I need.

What I was wondering is, if there is a pattern or something that will help me get only that part of the PDF. Looking at the plain text file it seems there are things that defines begin/end of lines, colors, etc.

Some of the extract data:

```
1 0 0 1 0 612 cm 0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 RG
28.35 -28.35 735.3 -526.95 re
W
n
0 0 0.502 sc
28.35 -65.5 735.3 -12.75 re
f
28.35 -543.9 735.3 -11.4 re
f
q
92.25 -28.35 560.9 -18 re
W
n
1 1 1 sc
92.25 -28.35 560.9 -18 re
f
BT
1 0 0 1 95.25 -39.1 Tm
0 0 0 sc
/i 10.75 Tf
(Name - Live) T
```

NOTE: the above is just partially the initial data from the page 2 to point out what I previously meant.

Is that data in a tabulation sort of thing and how could I extract only that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `PdfTextExtractor` as it will give you a little more human readable text out of the pdf:

```
for (int page = 2; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
    iResult.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Hi, indeed that does give it in a easier way but I think parsing it from the raw should be easier then from a plain text not ? I mean, with the raw it seems to exist some pattern that defines where the data is I just wanted to know if there is a list or some function to extract from the tables directly...

Comment: Yes, a pattern exists of course. This pattern is described in the PDF specification and is what iTextSharp already implements for you in order to parse the PDF. The PDF specification is like a 35MB of PDF file. Do you really want to read it to understand this pattern? Here's a link if you do: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: So I guess iTextSharp doesn't have a function that already have those patterns like BT, tf, etc... Even without reading the specifications, It does look simpler to go by it is pattern like BT/ET in between I have a set of data. Then for example `Tf (Assess) Tj` and what is inside the parenthesis is the actual data, but that is what I was looking for, if there is a parser or even within iTextSharp a function that recognizes that.

Comment: iTextSharp already extracts the whole text for you. If you want to be working with the raw data it is up to you to write your own parser.

Comment: Well thanks anyway, there seems to be also an ordering issue with the extracted text using the above, it doesn't come out in the same order as it is in the image. The house suburb and street comes before the lot.

Comment: Content can be ordered in a completely random order inside a PDF. That's why the TextRenderInfo (a class in iTextSharp) gives you coordinates of the baseline and other metrics. Please read the documentation: http://itextpdf.com/book/