# PDF to .txt using iTextSharp issues

Tags: pdf, powershell, text, itext

I've finally gotten a C# project loaded as a PowerShell module, and am able to convert a PDF to text, sort of.

Some of my PDFs seem to convert fine, others get cut off at the end, and some of them just simply give me output like this:

```
!nn!
Q9!r
!
!!
-;7!!
H*
Q0-.(;5!!n
#n%-,-Bn
!rn-;7!H+
(-;7
,-;7
,-;79
!-;7nnn;,-
n-n
n>-rn
n!!r
n+*,
,),+I-.n
@55=
!8
(
)%
rr-;7
Q!n-;7
n!Q
!!n
F3Q02
!8nH
@*825
-n-;7
-;7nrQ
&n!!-;7C4-;7
Kn>B)I!!!I
$rn==.=!
r*.//
@5>8636nKnn
```

I've checked the properties of the PDF files i'm testing with, and I can't find anything that sticks out as the reason a PDF outputs gibberish like above.

Can someone please give me some ideas on what else to look for and/or change?

Comment: Please provide the code used to extract text. Also, not all PDFs store text in the order that you read it and not all PDFs store textual information as true text. For instance, some design tools (like Adobe Illustrator) allow you to break text into vector points (convert to outlines) and this will destroy the textual information so the PDF only looks like it is made of text.

Comment: I can't take credit for this, but here goes (Convertfrom-PDF cmdlet inheriting from the PDFParser class):

Comment: http://www.beefycode.com/post/ConvertFrom-PDF-Cmdlet.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET

Comment: iTextSharp actually ships with some very smart PDF to text capabilities. I recommend that you investigate those instead of relying on the code from CodeProject which appears to take a more simplistic but error prone route. See this for a start http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471529/231316

Comment: I appreciate the advice, and I understand what you are saying.  I hate to begin with code that has already been written.  I did try to write some code from scratch for quite some time, but could not find a way to simply extract all text from a PDF (then develop some search logic from there).  I kept getting hung-up on extracting by page, then by lines, which were actually individual arrays of characters.  So, the frustration of not fully extracting all text led me to look for pre-written code.

Comment: It looks like the PDFs i'm having trouble with were created with PrimoPDF, which used CUSTOM encoding fonts.  I think this is probably the issue.

Comment: See this for extracting text line-by-line. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8451913/231316. Also, I'm almost 100% positive that the built-in extract methods take care of looking up text encoded using cmaps which it sounds like your PDF has.

Comment: Actually the issue is that you assume text to have a non-custom encoding. In earlier days pdf generators used to very often use standard encodings but nowadays you more and more often find non standard encoded fonts.  Thus, you won't be happy using a simple solution counting on standard encodings.

Comment: the LocationTextExtractionStrategy posted in the link you provided seems like it may work.  Any ideas on how to implement it in this .NET code?

Comment: for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
        {
            $strategy = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'            
            $currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy);
            [string[]]$Text += [system.text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::Convert( [system.text.encoding]::default, [system.text.encoding]::UTF8, [system.text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($currentText)));